# PHP editing text file on remote server not working

Tags: php, file, ftp

I have multiple sites, and have a text file on our main site with a list of domains to whitelist. I want to be able to edit this global file from each of the websites.

I have a couple of problems that I'm running into:

1. `file_exists()` and `ftp_delete()` are not finding the file even though it exists on the remote server.
2. `ftp_fput()` is adding a blank text file in the correct place with a zero filesize.

Here is my code:

```php
// Check if we are updating the whitelist
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    // Make sure we have something to add or remove
    if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] != '') {
        
        // Get the text we need to add or remove
        $add_or_remove_this = $_POST['update'];

        eri_update_global_whitelist( $add_or_remove_this, 'add' );

        // Say it was done
        echo '<br>Script Completed...<br>';
    }
}

echo '<form method="post">
    <textarea name="update" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>';


function eri_update_global_whitelist( $string, $add_or_remove = 'add' ) {
    // Validate the string
    $domains = explode( ',', str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($string)) );
    print_r($domains); // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

    // Add invalid domains here
    $invalid = [];

    // Cycle
    foreach ($domains as $key => $domain) {

        // Check if it contains a dot
        if (strpos($domain, '.') === false) {

            // If not, remove it
            unset($domains[$key]);

            // Add it to invalid array'
            $invalid[] = $domain;
        }
    }
    print_r($domains); // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

    // Only continue if we have domains to work with
    if (!empty($domains)) {

        // The whitelist filename
        $filename = 'email_domain_whitelist.txt';
        
        // File path on remote server
        $file_url = 'https://example.com/eri-webtools-plugin/data/'.$filename;

        // Get the file content
        $file_contents = file_get_contents( $file_url );

        // Only continue if we found the file
        if ($file_contents) {

            // Explode the old domains
            $old_domains = explode( ',', str_replace(' ', '', $file_contents) );
            print_r($old_domains); // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

            // Are we adding or removing
            if ($add_or_remove == 'add') {
                
                // Merge the arrays without duplicates
                $new_domains = array_unique (array_merge ($old_domains, $domains));
                
            } else {

                // Loop through them
                foreach ($old_domains as $key => $old_domain) {

                    // Check if it matches one of the new domains
                    if (in_array($old_domain, $domains)) {

                        // If so, remove it
                        unset($old_domains[$key]);
                    }
                }
                
                // Change var
                $new_domains = $old_domains;
            }
            print_r($new_domains); // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

            // Include the ftp configuration file 
            require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/eri-webtools-plugin/ftp_config.php'; 

            // Establishing ftp connection  
            $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server)
                or die("<br>Could not connect to $ftp_server");

            // If connected
            if ( $ftp_connection ) {

                // Log in to established connection with ftp username password 
                $login = ftp_login( $ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass ); 

                // If we are logged in
                if ( $login ){
                    echo '<br>Logged in successfully!';  // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

                    // Make passive
                    ftp_pasv($ftp_connection, true);

                    // File path to delete
                    $file_to_delete = 'https://example.com/eri-webtools-plugin/data/'.$filename;  // <-- NOT SURE HOW TO USE ABSOLUTE PATH ON REMOTE SERVER ??
                    
                    // Delete the old file
                    if (file_exists($file_to_delete)) {
                        if (ftp_delete($ftp_connection, $file_to_delete)) {
                            echo '<br>Successfully deleted '.$filename;
                        } else {
                            echo '<br>There was a problem while deleting '.$filename;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<br>File does not exist at: '.$file_to_delete;  // <-- RETURNS
                    }

                    // Create a new file
                    $open = fopen($filename, 'r+');

                    // If we didn't die, let's implode it
                    $new_domain_string = implode(', ', $new_domains);
                    print_r('<br>'.$new_domain_string); // <-- WORKS AS EXPECTED

                    // Write to the new text file
                    if (fwrite( $open, $new_domain_string )) {
                        echo '<br>Successfully wrote to file.'; // <-- RETURNS
                    } else {
                        echo '<br>Cannot write to file.';
                    }

                    // Add the new file
                    if (ftp_fput($ftp_connection, '/eri-webtools-plugin/data/2'.$filename, $open, FTP_ASCII)) {
                        echo '<br>Successfully uploaded '.$filename; // <-- RETURNS
                    } else {
                        echo '<br>There was a problem while uploading '.$filename;
                    }

                } else {
                    echo '<br>Could not login...';
                }

                // Close the FTP connection
                if(ftp_close($ftp_connection)) {
                    echo '<br>Connection closed Successfully!'; // <-- RETURNS
                } else {
                    echo '<br>Connection could not close...';
                }

            } else {
                echo '<br>Could not connect...';
            }

        } else {
            echo '<br>Could not find the file...';
        }

    } else {
        echo '<br>No valid domains to add or remove...';
    }

    // Check for invalid domains
    if (!empty($invalid)) {
        echo '<br>Invalid domains found: '.implode(', ', $invalid);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to use `fopen` to check it a remote file exists instead of `file_exists`.  I don't see a `file_delete` in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ftp_delete()`. I tried `ftp_delete()` without first checking if the file exists, and it also told me the file doesn't exist. @Alan

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I ditched `ftp_fput()` and replaced it with `ftp_put()`. Then I referred to the temporary file location on the local server instead of the `fopen()` like so:

```php
ftp_put($ftp_connection, '/eri-webtools-plugin/data/'.$filename, $filename, FTP_ASCII)
```

So to explain what's going on (in case someone else runs into this):

```php
// Name the temporary path and file, preferably the same name as what you want to call it.
// The path doesn't need to be specified. It just gets temporarily stored at the root and then deleted afterwards.
$filename = 'filename.txt';

// Create a new file by opening one that doesn't exist
// This will be temporarily stored on the local server as noted above
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w+');

// Write to the new file
fwrite( $fp, 'Text content in the file' );

// Add the file where you want it
ftp_put($ftp_connection, '/desination_folder/'.$filename, $filename, FTP_ASCII);

// Close the file
fclose($fp);
```

I ended up finding out that using `ftp_put()` will replace a file if it already exists, so there is no need to delete the old one like I was trying to.